# Passing multiple callbacks to a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to close a component once a user submits some text input.  Before I close, I want a few functions (based on the submitted text) to be called.

I tried passing multiple callbacks to the onSubmitEditing prop.  This didn't work since there was no guarantee that all my functions complete before the component unmounted.

So I'm wondering why this is allowed?

I ended up writing an exit function that wrapped everything I had to do before unmounting in a promise.  Is this the best practice for scenarios like this?

```
class AlbumCreateView extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      newAlbumName: '',
    }
    this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this)
    this._keyboardWillShow = this._keyboardWillShow.bind(this)
    this.exitFunction = this.exitFunction.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardWillShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this._keyboardWillShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount (e) {
    this.keyboardWillShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear)
    this.props.raiseKeyboard(0)
  }

  _keyboardWillShow (e) {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear)
    this.props.raiseKeyboard(e.endCoordinates.height)

  }

  _keyboardDidHide () {

  }
  newAlbumSaveHandler() {
    MySwiftClass.createAndSaveToNewAlbum(this.state.newAlbumName)
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear),
    this.props.raiseKeyboard(0)
  }
  exitFunction() { *****
    const saveAndDismissKeyboardPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //I want to make sure these these two functions are called before the component unmounts
      this.newAlbumSaveHandler()
      Keyboard.dismiss()
      resolve()
    })
    //this component lives in a modal, the following callback toggles the isVisible state in the parent and unmounts this component
    saveAndDismissKeyboardPromise.then(this.props.toggleModal)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.flatList}>
        <View style={styles.albumButton}>
        </View>
        <TextInput onSubmitEditing={this.exitFunction} *****
          keyboardType='default'
          autoFocus={true}
          autoCorrect={false}
          textAlign='center'
          onChangeText={(newAlbumName) => this.setState({newAlbumName})}
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
          style={{width: 200}}
        />

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here so we can see what you've done?

Comment: done - I put asterisks in key areas to try and make it easier to read.

Comment: What does `MySwiftClass.createAndSaveToNewAlbum` look like?

Comment: It's a native function that uses Apple's Photo Framework to create a new album and saves the the taken picture to that new album